# what if I used sour paint on my walls?

Tags: painting

I used sour smelling paint on my walls in my spare bedroom about 2 months ago and the smell is still there even after I used fresh paint and put two more coats of the fresh paint. What should I do.? Is it safe to be in that room.? It isn't as bad as it was but you can still smell it.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly you might be re-drywalling the whole room.  If you smell sour that is basically mold.  If you can smell it then it must be producing mold in the air which affects your family.  So you have two choices:

1. Tear down drywall and start over.
2. Go through a grueling process of using lacquer and paint removal products that are just horrible.  And now you have two more coats on top of it.  This will make your whole house smell and is just and absolute mess.  And the kicker, you could do this and still have smell problems.

Obviously using the paint was really dumb.  My rule is if I have to ask myself if I should use something or not, I don't unless a pro or research says its OK.

Comment: Man, that's a drag.

Comment: @iLikeDirt - yea sucks... Like $15 worth of bad paint will cost maybe 500+.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to tear down to the dry wall. Clean your walls with a bleach solution (1 part bleach to 10 parts water). Air dry. Use Kilz primer over the sour paint. It will seal in the odors and the bacteria.Then repaint with new paint. The odor will be gone.